# Touch of Flex Slider is not working

Tags: views, 7

I am using Flexsilder in Drupal7, and i also enabled touch FROM Admin .

But Flexslider is not working for pad using touch

Here is my link, where i am facing issue [this is my link where flex slider is implemented](http://nowlinkemoved.com)

Anybody can help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should try with different images. It works perfectly on my tablet and phone (both w8.1) you just can't drag it with your mouse, maybe thats why you tought it didn't work?